# Read last empty line of a text file in C++

Tags: c++, vector, fstream, iostream

I try

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string> readLines(string filename)
{
    ifstream infile(filename);
    vector<string> v;
    string line;
    bool good;
    do {
        good = getline(infile, line).good();
        if (!good) break; //<---- if exists, or not - is bad
        v.push_back(line);
    } while (good);
    return v;
}

int main() {
    auto v = readLines("test.txt");
    for (auto &line:v)
        cout << ">" << line << endl;
}
```

If I break loop, no last line in vector, if  no break - add empty line although not in file.
I want do precisely tests with test file and if exists last empty line is important.

Comment: `while (getline(infile, line) && !line.empty()) { v.push_back(line); }` ??

Comment: not sure if I understand the quesiton. Your file has an empty line at the end, but this code does not read it correctly? And you want to read the last empty line and include it in the vector?

Comment: while (getline(infile, line) && !line.empty()) { v.push_back(line); } stops at first empty line; I have two files: one has empty line at end, second file not. I expect after reading first file, empty string at end vector and after reading second file  - not.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<string> readLines(string filename)
{
    ifstream infile(filename);
    vector<string> v;
    string line;
    bool readedNewline;
    if (infile.peek() != EOF)
    while(true) {
        readedNewline = getline(infile, line).good();
        v.push_back(line);
        if (!readedNewline) break;
    }
    return v;
}

int main() {
    auto v = readLines("test.txt");
    for (auto &line:v)
        cout << ">" << line << endl;
}
```

getline().good() returns true if after line is newline char.
Push to vector last not good(), thus I must check if file is not empty (peek())